# Validate ACN (Australian Company Number) in C#

Tags: c#

How to validate an ASIC ACN (Australian Company Number) in C#?

The [validation rules](http://asic.gov.au/for-business/starting-a-company/how-to-start-a-company/australian-company-numbers/australian-company-number-digit-check/) will be static over time so for the sake of brevity have not repeated them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/// <summary>
/// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781957
/// </summary>
public bool IsValidAcn(string acn)
{
    int[] weightings = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    var accumulatedSum = 0;

    acn = acn?.Replace(" ", ""); // strip spaces

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(acn) || !Regex.IsMatch(acn, @"^\d{9}$"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Sum the multiplication of all the digits and weights
    for (int i = 0; i < weightings.Length; i++)
    {
        accumulatedSum += Convert.ToInt32(acn.Substring(i, 1)) * weightings[i];
    }

    var remainder = accumulatedSum % 10;

    var expectedCheckDigit = (10 - remainder == 10) ? 0 : (10 - remainder);

    var actualCheckDigit = Convert.ToInt32(acn.Substring(8, 1));

    return expectedCheckDigit == actualCheckDigit;
}
```

xUnit tests to keep your tech lead happy...

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("604475587", true)]
[InlineData("00 258 9460", true)]
[InlineData("604475587asdfsf", false)]
[InlineData("444", false)]
[InlineData(null, false)]
public void IsValidAcn(string acn, bool expectedValidity)
{
    var sut = GetSystemUnderTest();
    Assert.True(sut.IsValidAcn(acn) == expectedValidity);
}
```